# Can we use Postgres for testing and Mongo for development environment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, rspec

I have a rails application running with MongoDB for the development environment. We're planning to migrate to an SQL Database (PostgreSQL) and in the process we're first adding RSpec using PostgreSQL as our test database.

I do understand following points:

- We've ActiveRecord ORM for connecting rails with an SQL Based DB and
  Mongoid for MongoDB.
- We've migrations for our test env and no such migrations for dev environment.
- Our models will turn into this:

  `class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Mongoid::Document
  end`

Will there be any blockers if I go with such approach and start adding rspec using PostgreSQL database ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend against this as you're testing apples and oranges. If you're eager to start testing, mock/stub out your database calls (See the build_stubbed method with FactoryGirl https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test). That way you're testing the behavior of your app without being coupled to the database implementation.